# How to disable or change the android boot animation?

Tags: android, boot

I'm developing an App, and the client requires that we have to disable the entire android loading animation, the first UI, etc. The task is to show the client animation for loading then moves to the application directly from the loading animation without showing any Android UI.

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What you are describing cannot be done from an app. The "android loading animation" that is part of the "booting UI" is part of the device ROM and cannot be modified by an app.

Comment: Clarification of the title

Answer (score 0):

Look for  system/media and system/customize/resource and data/local. If you find a bootanimation.zip file, replace it with your own custom animations, Also the boot flash screen is sometimes not replaceable unless you have a custom rom which you can flash on the device. 
You need root permissions to perform this.